# Multiple answers to not true statement

Tags: php

I never used php before, but now I need a contact form on my website. I'm following a tutorial and in it they make a captcha by writing:

```
else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != 'sky') {
    echo '<p>You answered incorrectly</p>';
    }
```

My question is simple:
What is the correct syntax of defining multiple answers to the captcha?
So instead of "sky" the user could also answer "Sky" or "skies" or "heaven" for example and still get the captcha right?

Comment: Ive never used php either, but programming languages use conditional operators such as and and or. In the example above this already checks 2 conditions, separated by &&. Simple add More && to chain up expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$answers = array('sky','skies','whatever');

if ...
else if ($_POST['submit'] && !in_array($human,$answers)) {
    echo '<p>You answered incorrectly</p>';
}
```

manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Not to be nit-picky, but maybe a good idea to use strtolower($human) to be case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks! But is there no simpler way to do this (one that doesn't need an array)? Would something like: != 'sky' && 'heaven' not work?

Comment: That would not work. You'll need an array. Do you have any real reason to not want to use an array?

Comment: @Sonypackman - it would work, but it's a lot more difficult to maintain that using an array. You'd need to format the if as `if ($_POST['submit'] && ($human == 'sky' || $human == 'heaven' ....` But storing the answers in an array is a lot easier.

Comment: The only real reason I'm looking for a simpler answer is because I can't fully understand the code in your array example. Mainly: why do you include $human in ($human,$answers)? Why not just "$answers" inside the parenthesis?

Comment: Okay I checked that page and it said the order is this: 
    in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE     ] )
And that would search for needle in haystack. So are you not searching for "human" in "answers" then instead of "answers" in "human"?
Sorry for being such a newbie but I feel it's important to undestand the code I put online.

Comment: The needle is the input that you get from the user. The haystack is the pile of correct answers that you might accept. You are searching the haystack to see if the needle is in there.